# Spring Security 6 redirects to /error instead of returning 401 status

Tags: java, spring-security, error-handling, migration

I am migrating an application to Spring Security 6 and I have an odd problem. Our app authenticates users externally via a cookie key (it is an internal app and that is how our security system functions) and we have two security configurations, API and Web.

In previous versions of Spring Security when an attempt was made to access a secured API resource, the service would enter an `ApiAuthorizationErrorHandler` which would return a 401 unauthorized if credentials were not found or 403 forbidden if some other exception occurred.

Web configuration has a different error handler which returns a redirect to the company log-in web. Once I migrated to Spring Security 6 at first I had issues with everything throwing 403s with `Access Denied`. I've managed to mitigate that issue by adding

```java
.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.INCLUDE).permitAll()
```

but now the following seems to happen:

1. A request is made for a resource by an unauthenticated user (user without authentication cookie)
2. Request goes through all the filters and ends up in the error handler
3. Error handler calls `response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized")`
4. Instead of returning the 401 response, a redirect or something is made to `/error`
5. `/error` enters the filter chain, this time since it's not prefixed by `/api` it enters the web filter chain
6. Web error handler is invoked and a 302 redirect is returned with the company log-in web as the destination.

Steps 4, 5, and 6 did not happen in old versions of spring security with the identical setup.

This is a sample of what API security configuration looks like:

```java
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain authFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .securityMatcher(Mappings.ROOT_CONTEXT_PATH + "/api/auth/roles")
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.INCLUDE).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
    requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);

    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf
            .csrfTokenRepository(getCsrfTokenRepository())
            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
        );

    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);

    var preAuthenticatedAuthenticationFilter = new PreAuthenticatedCustomAuthenticationFilter();
    preAuthenticatedAuthenticationFilter.setCheckForPrincipalChanges(true);
    preAuthenticatedAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

    http
        .addFilterAfter(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationFilter, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)

    http
        .authenticationProvider(Objects.requireNonNull(externalAuthProvider));
        
    http
        .anonymous().disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new ApiAuthorizationErrorHandler())
            .and();

    return http.build();
}
```

```java
public class ApiAuthorizationErrorHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (authException instanceof AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Forbidden");
        }
    }
```

What makes the request be forwarded to `/error` and how can I disable it and get the old behavior back?